# List 2 first and 2 last pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyway of showing the 2 first pages in one `<ul>` and the last 2 pages in another `<ul>` in WordPress?

On my page I have two different lists for the navigation bar:

```
<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Limit the data `wp_list_pages()` gets by 2 and the first one should show ASC and last one DESC - something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_order=ASC&number=2'); ?>
</ul>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_order=DESC&number=2'); ?>
</ul>
```

> number  (integer) Sets the number of Pages to display. This causes the
>   SQL LIMIT value to be defined. Default to no LIMIT.

Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: They are both showing all of the pages, also the numbers are ID's.

Comment: I was asking for the 2 first and 2 last pages in two different ul's, so it's not ID's I am talking about mate.

Comment: try this <?php wp_list_pages('sort_order=ASC&number=2'); ?>